# I upload file using fs.writefileSync(), When i open the uploaded file, it show invalid image. here i attach my code

Tags: node.js

Here i use fs.writeFileSync. The file is successfully uploaded, but the invalid image show

```
const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);//originalname:Remainder filled.png  

      const name = file.fieldname;
      let imageName = file.originalname.replace(' ', '_');
      let fileNameArray = imageName.split('.');
      const fileName = fileNameArray[0] + '_' + getIndianCurrentUnixDateTime() + fileExtension;
       fs.writeFileSync(uploadPath + fileName, function(err) { //uploadPath = 'C:/files/';
        if (err) throw err;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not call `fs.writeFileSync` correctly. It passes a filename and a callback.

`fs.writeFileSync` expects a filename, data, and an optional options object.

See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options